# Keep the ServerSocket listening to the client

Tags: java, sockets

I have implemented Andorid App which communicates with the server side by socket (TCP). When I click the button in the Android app a communication is being established between the app and server side as well as messages are being exchange.
To communicate with the server again I have to run the server in Eclipse once again. I want to run the server side once and when no data in the clientSocket buffer the server should listen again if the Android user sends a new request
 to the server.I tried to mange that by using the `Runnable` class but I still have to run the server side in Eclipse again? How can I get it to work?

```
public class Server{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Cg2AapiServer.startServer();

    }

    private static void startServer() {

        Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(27015);
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                    Cg2AapiServer.bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                    Cg2AapiServer.outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                    Cg2AapiServer.smartCard = new SmartCard();
                    Cg2AapiServer.handleConnection();

                    Cg2AapiServer.bufferedInputStream.close();
                    Cg2AapiServer.outputStream.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.err.println("Unable to process client request");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
        serverThread.start();

        System.out.println("At the end of the startServer method!");

    }


    private static void handleConnection() throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer receiveBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Cg2AapiServer.RECEIVE_BUFFER_LENGTH);
        int readBytes = 0;
        while (true) {
            readBytes = Cg2AapiServer.bufferedInputStream.read(receiveBuffer.array(), receiveBuffer.position(),
                    receiveBuffer.remaining());
            System.out.println("readBytes: " + readBytes);
            if (readBytes < 0) {
                             // What should I do here when the readBytes = -1
                Cg2AapiServer.startServer(); //With this line I am getting the error below.
                break;
            }
       }

}
```

**Error**

> Unable to process client request java.net.BindException: Address
>   already in use: JVM_Bind  at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)  at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)     at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:237)   at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(ServerSocket.java:128)   at
>   Cg2AapiServer$1.run(Cg2AapiServer.java:42)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Address already in use: JVM_Bind. You need to stop the old running server and then run it. This error means there is something already listening on the port number you chose.